# How do I cancel a Schengen tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, visa-cancellation

I currently have a valid Schengen tourist visa that expires next year, issued by the French Consulate in Saudi Arabia.

I am going to a 60-day study abroad program in Italy and they require a student visa. I went to the Italian Consulate in Boston and they asked me to go to the French Consulate and cancel my visa. However, the French Consulate said that I needed to contact the French Embassy in Saudi to cancel the visa.

How can I cancel my tourist visa if I am currently in the United States? My Italian student visa application is due tomorrow morning.

Comment: Both the Italian Consulate and the French consulate in Boston are jokers. I had the French Consulate in Washington DC cancel my German Schengen visa in 2005 under the same circumstances, after which they issued me a French Schengen. Some of these officials do not know what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Consular officials from all Schengen member states have the authority to cancel Schengen visas issued by other member states according to the Schengen Code.

[CONSOLIDATED version of the Handbook](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf)  Refer to Page 101

> A visa may be annulled by the competent authorities **of another Member
>   State**, in which case the authorities of the Member State that issued
>   the visa shall be informed of such annulment.

Personally I had the French Consulate in Washington DC cancel my German Schengen visa in 2005 under the somewhat similar circumstances, after which they issued me a French Schengen.